# Bootstrap modal jquery hidden does not work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a problem with my modal.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#mdProduction">production</button>
```

modal:

```
<div id="mdProduction" class="modal fade" role="dialog" >
   <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:45%;">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">production</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           some content
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#mdProduction').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 alert("Hello World!");
})
```

But i don't get any alert. 
I also tried "window.alert", but it doesn't work neither.

This is just an example.
What I want is to trigger a function, when the modal gets hidden.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event your are using is working well :

```js
$('#mdProduction').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  alert("Hello World!");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="mdProduction" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is a small modal.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mdProduction">Open Small Modal</button>
```

I think the problem comes from the way you are opening the dialog. Can you share the code where you try to open the dialog ?

Comment: i think, i know, what the problem is. (see edit). i'm using jquery 1.12.0

Comment: As you can find there https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/bower.json the min version for bootstrap is 1.9.1. Can you share a little jsfiddle to show your problem ?

Comment: i tried the version you used, but it doesn't work.
And i never had problems before with something else.

Comment: Maybe your browser doesn't allow to show alert. Can you try with a `console.log("hello workd")` ? https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/23b07yLe/

Comment: in other situations alerts are shown. and nothing appears in the console

Comment: You should provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help on SO

Comment: i got it...i implement the html head with an external file. now i copied the bootstrap and jquery directly in the file and it works.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your html is incorrect I believe. It should be:

```
<div id="mdProduction" class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            some information
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```